# How to subtract a value from one column based on the value of another in R?

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataframe with a list of IDs of 1-2000 and each one of these IDs has multiple collections timepoints (each new collection is a new row). I have removed timepoint 1 for those with an ID of less than 1177. What I want to do now is to subtract 1 from the remaining collections for all samples that are less than 1177. For example, collection 2 will become 1 and 3 will become 2.
What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

I think that some code and an example `df` would help us to understand.
However, you may do something like this

```
df$collection <- ifelse(df$ID > 1177, df$collection - 1, df$collection )
```

This only works if `collection` is a numerical vector. `df` is your dataframe